# MSYS2 endian.h no such file or directory when building protocol-buffer

Tags: protocol-buffers, msys2

I'm currently trying to build protobuf under windows using MSYS2 MINGW64.

What I did is (under MINGW64 console) :

```
./autogen.sh
./configure --prefix=/buildMingw
make
```

Make command lead to this :

```
  CXX      google/protobuf/any_lite.lo
In file included from ./google/protobuf/message_lite.h:47,
                 from ./google/protobuf/any.h:38,
                 from google/protobuf/any_lite.cc:31:
./google/protobuf/io/coded_stream.h:137:10: fatal error: endian.h: No such file or directory
  137 | #include <endian.h>  // __BYTE_ORDER
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I'm not familiar with Makefile, by looking at it I have spot thoses two things :

```
pkgincludedir = $(includedir)/protobuf //<- pkgincludedir is never used in this makefile
...
includedir = ${prefix}/include 
infodir = ${datarootdir}/info
install_sh = ${SHELL} /home/user/protobuf/install-sh
libdir = ${exec_prefix}/lib
libexecdir = ${exec_prefix}/libexec
localedir = ${datarootdir}/locale
localstatedir = ${prefix}/var
mandir = ${datarootdir}/man
mkdir_p = $(MKDIR_P)
oldincludedir = /usr/include //<-- This variable is never used in this makefile
```

the file in *oldincludedir* lead to endian.h, so I just tried to swap path in *includedir* and *oldincludedir* but same error occure, what I'm missing ?